# Using standard edit pages in Force.com Sites

Tags: force.com-sites

I want to create a form which is available externally, and allow unauthenticated users to create records.  Is there a way to use standard edit pages in a Force.com site, or can you only display VF pages?

Comment: Is it a custom object data? provide edit access to the object for guest user profile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard detail and edit page are not available in Force.com Sites for guest (unauthenticated) users.

If you want to create a form to submit records (something like your own Web-to-Case) you'll need to create a Visualforce page and then add the page to your site.